# How to run a shellscript from backgorund in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the below command but it is not working, i see the process is created and killed automatically

BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup /Folder1/job1.sh > /Folder2/Job1.log 2>&1 &

**Jenkins Output:**

```
[ssh-agent] Using credentials user1 (private key for user1)
[job1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins19668363456535073453.sh

    + BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
    + nohup /Folder1/job1.sh
    $ ssh-agent -k
    unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
    echo Agent pid 8765 killed;
    [ssh-agent] Stopped.
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Is that 2 cmds? 1)`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` (insert newline or ";") 2) `nohup ... &` ? What is your "pipeline step?"

Comment: What makes you think that that your script is killed? The output above just indicates that an existing `ssh-agent` is killed, which is expected behavior with option `-k`.

Comment: @Alex After I trigger the build, i don't see the job  is running in my machine. So this was the output. My thinking is that it(jobs.sh) should be running in background. When I use ps -ef| grep jobs.sh, I don't see the job is running. That's means this jenkins job has triggered the Job1.sh and killed it.

Comment: Could you post the (relevant) content of `job1.sh`? From the output, it appears that that script just invokes `ssh-agent -k` and then terminates normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have run a command without the nohup, so you may try to use:

```
sh """
    BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /Folder1/job1.sh > /Folder2/Job1.log 2>&1 &
"""
```

In my case, I did not need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT because the process I was running captured all errors and displayed on STDOUT directly.

Answer (score 0):

We use [daemonize](https://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize) for that. It properly starts the program in the background and does not kill it when the parent process (`bash`) exits.